# Secrets Key do Asp.net Core 2.1 no aws

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-aws, .net-core

Preciso armazenar chaves secretas no aws para que eu possa rodar minha aplicação, mas não sei aonde armazeno essas chaves secretas, e como as chamo em minha aplicação, na minha aplicação local tudo funciona perfeitamente mas,quando subo para o aws recebo o seguinte erro:

> ArgumentException: The 'ClientId' option must be provided.

Exemplo:

```
{
  "Authentication:Google:ClientId": "valor",
  "Authentication:Google:ClientSecret": "valor",

  "Authentication:Facebook:AppId": "valor",
  "Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret": "valor"
}
```

Quero armazenar esses valores, para que minha autenticação pelo google e facebook possam funcionar também, em minha aplicação online.

Comment: Adicione mais detalhes, onde você está armazenando as informações acima e onde está obtendo o erro

Comment: @LeandroAngelo esse é o problema, não sei aonde armazenar no aws. Localmente consigo compilar e usar pois armazeno no `Manager User Secrets`, recebo o erro no aws simplesmente ao clicar na url do projeto

Comment: dê uma olhada nesse artigo https://medium.com/@jonvines/using-aws-secrets-manager-with-dotnet-core-a44b54bba8d4

Comment: Para usar o AWS Secrets Manager você vai precisar codificar e usar o SDK do AWS. ou então você pode colocar essas configurações nas variáveis de ambiente do AWS que o ASP.NET Core já faz a alteração automaticamente. Qual serviço vc está usando para hospedar?

Comment: Criei pelo Elastic Beanstalk, então coloco essas variáveis como variável de ambiente, e as pego em meu programa ?

Comment: Isso: Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"]  na classe program vc precisa chamar o AddEnvironmentVariables() depois do CreateDefaultBuilder e dentro de ConfigureAppConfiguration. Se não funcionar com ":" na várivável de ambiente, tente com "__" dois underscore, mas no Configuration é sempre ":",ok?